# How to disable BasicBlock Utils Pass？

Tags: llvm

I want to disable optimization for basic block merging during LLVM compilation. This is all I found. What if I want to disable an optimization individually?

```
The option ‘-disable-llvm-passes’ disables all LLVM passes, even those that run at -O0. Passing -O1 (or any optimization level other than -O0) avoids that the ‘optnone’ attribute is added. clang file.c -c -O1 -Xclang -disable-llvm-passes -emit-llvm -S -o - | opt -polly-canonicalize -S
```

Comment: Merging basic blocks isn't one single optimisation, it's something many passes do. There's a utility function to do it. Several passes call it, and so do several other utility functions, which are in turn called by quite a few passes. I suggest setting a breakpoint in `llvm::MergeBlockIntoPredecessor`, run your code under a debugger, look at the call stack each time the breakpoint hits, find out which passes you really want to disable and which ones don't matter to you, and then disable the passes you want to.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks!! I'd like to ask one more question. If I use the new pass to insert multiple statements into each base block in the program, will these statements be recompiled to produce an executable that is out of order due to optimization features in LLVM or cut off by the original program instructions? (Especially when it comes to register-related operations, which are very important to me)

Comment: SO frowns on this kind of subject change… but generally, LLVM cannot do anything that is out of order, because LLVM's order is defined such that that's not possible. In code such as a = b + c, the assignment *has* to be after whatever code computes b and c, see? If you see reordering you don't want, then your code generated buggy IR. If you depend on c to be computed after b and your code didn't make that clear, that's your bug, and your bug only. LLVM will use CPU pipelines and superscalar execution as much as your code allows.

Comment: I see. I will reconsider my coding problem, thanks a lot！